# Driving NEMA17 Stepper motor using leadshine driver

Tags: stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I'm trying to drive a NEMA17 stepper motor using [LEADSHINE driver](http://leadshine.com/productDetail.aspx?type=products&category=stepper-products&producttype=stepper-drives&subtype=general-stepper-drives&series=dm&model=dm556).
At the beginning of rotation Motor turns few steps in opposite direction and then turns toward the given direction. Why this is happening?
Here is the Arduino code:

```
const int pwm = 12; 
const int dir =11 ; 
const int enable3 = 24;// enable pin 
int delaymicros = 500; //duration of pwm
String  str1;
void setup() {      
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.setTimeout(1);

    pinMode(pwm,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(dir,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(enable3,OUTPUT);

    digitalWrite(pwm,LOW);
    digitalWrite(dir,LOW);        
}

void loop() {
     digitalWrite(enable3,LOW);  //Disable Motor
     if(Serial.available() > 0){
          String str = Serial.readString();
          Serial.flush();

          if((str.indexOf("x") > -1)){ //Move Clockwise if "x" is received via serial 
               digitalWrite(enable3,HIGH);  //Enable Motor
               for(int i=0;i<800;i++){   
                    digitalWrite(dir,LOW);  //Clockwise Direction
                    digitalWrite(pwm,HIGH);
                    delayMicroseconds(delaymicros*2);
                    digitalWrite(pwm,LOW);
                    delayMicroseconds(delaymicros*2); 
               }
          }
          if((str.indexOf("y") > -1)){//Move Counterclockwise if "y" is received via serial             
               digitalWrite(enable3,HIGH);
               for(int i=0;i<800;i++){   
                    digitalWrite(dir,HIGH); // Counterclockwise Direction
                    digitalWrite(pwm,HIGH);
                    delayMicroseconds(delaymicros*2);
                    digitalWrite(pwm,LOW);
                    delayMicroseconds(delaymicros*2);                               
                }
           }     
     }
}
```

Comment: Because it is initialized LOW?  Why?? is this a test to eliminate hysteresis with ramp down in rate.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I'm trying to control some steppers using serial commands. Motor should turn clockwise if "x" command is received and counterclockwise for "y". Motor enable pin is activated (High) if serial commands are available otherwise it is disabled(Low).

Comment: The motor position is undefined until the controller (driver) is enabled. So when it is first enabled it will jump to the position defined by the controller (this can cause it to move opposite from the next pulse command). The controller has hidden the details of the stepper motor operation from you. Read about stepper motors and you will understand what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the stepper position is out of sync with the driver they will often do this until the driver and rotor positions align.

This is why normal practise to to 'home' the motor on system startup and then leave the driver enabled (so the rotor is held by the fields in the correct position), any time you need to take the driver off line you should probably redo the motor homing operation.

Note that if your motor has limited travel in one direction, it is wise to run it a few dozen steps away from the home position before running it back onto the limit switch, this ensures that the thing is synchronised before it hits the limit.

In this steppers are markedly inferior to proper servo drives, but are simpler to operate.